# How to enable and disable native menu buttons in Adobe AIR?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, native

I'm using Adobe AIR 3.9 to create a desktop app for Windows. I'm using a native menu for the navigation. How to enable and disable those native menu buttons?

The menu code:

```
stage.nativeWindow.menu = new NativeMenu(); 
stage.nativeWindow.menu.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectCommandMenu); 
fileMenu = stage.nativeWindow.menu.addItem(new NativeMenuItem("Menu")); 
fileMenu.submenu = createFileMenu(); 

 var fileMenu:NativeMenu = new NativeMenu(); 
 fileMenu.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectCommandMenu); 
 newCommand = fileMenu.addItem(new NativeMenuItem("Contact")); 
 newCommand.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, setContact); 
 newCommand.keyEquivalent = "n";
```

Comment: You can answer the question by yourself so it won't stay opened and let people like me browse it :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov How to do it?

Comment: There's an answer field right below, so just post your answer there and accept it :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov Done! Have a great weekend :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, just found it: Use `fileMenu.enabled = false` to disable the menu.